# Film about a monkey man and a foggy mystical world

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic, magical-creatures

In 1995 or so, I saw a film about a monkey man which was some sort of secondary character, the main character probably a human, and maybe some other weird stuff I don't quite remember. There was a toy store a couple of blocks from my house (South America btw). Soon after seeing the movie, I found toys related to the movie there.

The monkey man had a very distinct look. I've seen *Planet of the Apes* and all, but this was different. Maybe not even monkey man but ape looking or weird like that. Light yellow skin / hair monster creature.

And I remember the ambiance, like a foggy mystical world and they were going to some castle or something. I remember the camera angle of the scene (very little of the movie that I can remember): the camera was looking kinda up a foggy mystical hill land, maybe going to a castle or something. They were a small clique, like, man woman kid and monsters or something like that. Your typical fantasy movie stuff.

If it was a dream it was almost too elaborate. And when was it from? 95? Or an old 70s movie? If it was an old one, why would there be toys still being sold as if it had just come out? And so on and so forth.

Comment: Live action? Or a cartoon?

Comment: [*Journey to the West?*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_media_adaptations_of_Journey_to_the_West) There have been [many film adaptations by 1995](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_media_adaptations_of_Journey_to_the_West#Films).There have also been [several TV adaptations by the mid-1990s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_media_adaptations_of_Journey_to_the_West#Television_series).

Comment: FuzzyBots - Live Action. Also, i forgot to say it could perfectly have been a show and not just a film.

Comment: Lexible. No i dont think thats it. Im looking that up right now, as we speak. Also I think the fact im saying "monkey man" its probably messing with the search. Im thinking it was maybe another type of creature. But i cannot get anything more than that it was brown and maybe hairy. Either ways Ill keep trying.

Comment: "Land of the Lost" is pretty close. 70s show with a 90s remake also. They have a character named "Stink" who is indeed an ape man, but the action figure looks honestly not very good. Howerver the style of the show is close. Im not sure what to think lol.

Comment: Could the "ape" be Gwildor from the Masters of the Universe movie? (The toys would have been everywhere)

Comment: Interesting, but no, thats not it. It was more of a thin tall character. That is a new one to me anyways, so thats cool lol. Thanx.

Comment: Just in case it slipped anyone, im starting to think it may have been Stink, from the 91' version of Land of the Lost. The action figure looks shitty tho lol. But the box it came in, looking it up on google, seems a bit familiar.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is “Monkey”

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_(TV_series)

Although the original is Japanese, it has been shown in the UK and probably elsewhere with English dubbing.

Each episode is an instalment of the journey of a small band - the clique you describe. The fog you describe is a typical effect used.

Comment: tomi - Thats a nice one, but Land of the Lost is still closer to the image in my mind. Thanks anyways.